# Replace "add new comment" link with image in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-comments

Is there an easy way to convert Drupal "add new comment" link into an "add new comment" gif image?

Syntax that adds link appears to be

```
 <?php if ($links): ?>
    <div class="links"><?php print $links; ?></div>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Yes, but I can only describe it in English, and slightly vaguely (hence comment, not answer). This is a module side alteration, not something you can just theme. Basically, implement the hook that alters node links, and wherever you encounter the "add new comment" link, replace it with an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are some techniques, go wild :) http://stopdesign.com/archive/2003/03/07/replace-text.html#notes

Answer (score 0):

$links is built in your template.php and modules can add to it.

$links is a `<ul>` and that particular link is `<li class="comment_add">`

you can use css to give li.comment_add a{background=..} and use a str_replace in one of your themename_node_preprocess(&$vars) and remove "Add new comment" from $vars['links']